# tsql login failed but management studio can connect

Tags: sql-server, django, sql-server-2012, pymssql

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL Server instance using tsql (to troubleshoot not being able to connect with django-pymssql).

I can connect fine to the server (running on Amazon RDS, latest SQL Server version from on there) from a VM running SQL Server management studio, but from my native Ubuntu 15.10 env I get a login failed error.

Using the following:

`tsql -H <hostname> -p 1433 -U <user> -P <mypassword>`

I get:

`locale is "en_GB.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 18456 (severity 14, state 1) from EC2AMAZ-U1TAK71 Line 1:
    "Login failed for user 'sa'."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server`

As I can connect in management studio with mixed mode auth using the same creds I'm suspecting this isn't the real error.

Anyone have any ideas how I can troubleshoot?

tsql -C shows:

`Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes`

Thanks loads for any pointers.!

(Accidentally posted this to AskUbuntu so have moved here. Sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. Turns out it was down to the password being too long. I experimented with it, and any password longer than 30 characters didn't work. Seems to be a known issue with freetds.

Thanks.